# Variadic function crashes when an extra argument is provided

Tags: c++

I am currently working on a project which involves the use of the PDCurses library to manipulate the cursor position during execution, and I wrote a printf wrapper so that text colors could be switched on a per print basis. When porting this program from VC++ 2008 to VS2019, it was found that said printf wrapper would crash with an access violation when attempting to print strings, but not when printing any other type.

Unsure of the cause, I wrote a small test program to try and see if the problem really was the variadic function, and turns out that this crash only occurs when an extra argument is appended to the function.

This prints successfully:

```c
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void pdprint(const char* str, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, str);

    // Print the string
    vprintf(str, args);
    fflush(stdout);
    va_end(args);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pdprint("Hello World\n");
    pdprint("This %d is a %s\n", 1, "test");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

This, does not (please note the extra argument on the `pdprint` function, which is unused in this case but utilizing it in the function leads to the same result):

```c
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void pdprint(const char* str, int color, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, str);

    // Print the string
    vprintf(str, args);
    fflush(stdout);
    va_end(args);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pdprint("Hello World\n", 0);
    pdprint("This %d is a %s\n", 0, 1, "test");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Edit:
I have noticed that swapping around the order of the `color` and `str` arguments no longer leads to crashes, so I guess the better question is why? Shouldn't `va_list` only take into account the variadic arguments along with the string?

Edit:
Ok, it turns out that the *last* argument before the variable argument list is what must be passed into the `va_start` function, as outlined in this page:
https://linux.die.net/man/3/va_start
I had completely missed this subtlety. Thank you to everyone!

Comment: Trying to print `1` via `%s` invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: %s is expecting a string, you are putting 1 instead, I'm not sure what the question is here. if this wasn't crashing before you were simply lucky and relying on undefined behavior.

Comment: @Borgleader Please note the new, second argument to the pdprint function in the second code block. I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: You’re passing the wrong argument to `va_start`.

Comment: @molbdnilo Are you not able to bypass the requirement of a count argument by simply passing in a formatted string? Such as the example provided at the end of here:  https://linux.die.net/man/3/va_start

Comment: You should do `va_start(args, color)` in second version of `pdprint`.

Comment: @Buu342 I don’t understand what you’re getting at. You need to pass the name of the last argument before the varargs; `color`, not `str`.

Comment: @molbdnilo Ohhh I see, I completely missed the subtlety with the last argument.

Comment: When you have this statement va_start(args, str); the ellipses ... must follow the variable called str in your function. Also the ... must be the last argument in the function signature. That means you move int color to the start of the prototype.